# Can solutions of GR have non-zero genus?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, topology

Imagine there is "cavity" in one's locally Lorentzian manifold (the manifold has non-zero genus). Have these kind of solutions in general relativity been considered? Is there any experiment one can do to prove we live in a non-zero genus world?

Comment: Have you considered a thin spherical shell asymptotically collapsing to its own Schwarzschild radius in the infinite coordinate time to form a black hole with nothing inside?

Comment: Sounds interesting ... I wonder what it's corresponding stress energy tensor would look like?

Comment: Check this out: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/414695/whats-inside-a-frozen-star

Comment: As an example, you can introduce flat Lorentzian metric on torii.

Comment: Consider to restrict the question to vacuum solutions only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any manifold, regardless of its properties, is a solution to the Einstein field equations for some stress-energy tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$, providing it admits a metric, $g_{\mu\nu}$.

In theory, you are free to pick your favourite algebraic manifold of genus $g$, compute the metric and find its corresponding stress-energy tensor.

However, if we restrict the stress-energy, say by requiring that $T_{\mu\nu}$ be infinitely differentiable, then we also restrict the space of allowable metrics. Likewise, if we demand the manifold be globally hyperbolic, which is a frequent requirement due to the implication on causality, then we also restrict possible solutions.

Based on a cursory search, I cannot find any classification of genus $g$ spacetime solutions yet. However, in the paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.09614) it is written that,

> In the current paper we study that equation on closed 2-dimensional
>   surfaces that have genus $>0$. We derive all the solutions assuming
>   the embeddability in 4-dimensional spacetime that satisfies the vacuum
>   Einstein equations...

It seems we can have sub-manifolds in spacetime which do have non-zero genus, and are sensible solutions to the vacuum Einstein field equations, meaning at least $T_{\mu\nu}$ is physically sensible, being zero.

Comment: Thank you for answering! But what about the "Is there any experiment one can do to prove we live in a non-zero genus world?" Like surely having non-zero genus would affect the CMB, etc?

Comment: @MoreAnonymous Well, it's the same for any solution you're considering. If you think the spacetime has a particular genus, compute the physical consequences of such a spacetime and then you can design experiments from that.