# Gravitational redshift inside a thin shell black hole

Tags: black-holes, gravitational-redshift

I got working on a cosmology problem that ultimately got into black holes, specifically thin shell black holes.  This is a black hole where all its mass is in a thin shell with the Schwarzschild radius.  Suppose the universe is such a thin shell black hole, as some say. If one could measure redshifts of light inside such a black hole universe, what would be the gravitational redshift of light that would be seen at any given point for a photon that was emitted inwards from the shell?  Could this be the Hubble redshift?  I am not so much interested in knowing things like why such an object might be impossible, but in the actual values.  What would be the formula to give the values starting from the shell and moving to the centre?

I noticed in the Wikipedia page for gravitational redshift  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift  In the section on "Spherically symmetric ..." they give some formulae which could be valuable if one were looking at points outside the shell.  Here I'm looking inside.  I'm aware of a number of similar questions that have been posted, but they don't cover this.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: What's the metric of such a spacetime?  You'd need to know that before you could answer the question.

Comment: As observed from outside, the speed of light inside would be zero. The metric of such a space time splits into separate metrics for space and time. Your question is answered here (probably in more details that you wanted): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310040 - For even more options also check this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/414695

Comment: Michael, I assume that this thin shell black hole universe has an internal Schwarzschild metric, given the spherical geometry.  It does not have the standard FLRW metric, as expansion is not happening.  (My explanation for the Hubble redshift is connected with this question.)  Safesphere, those links go too deep into the black hole physics!  I should have added I have a mechanism to keep the black hole universe from collapsing to a singularity.  Perhaps I should have started off by asking what the gravitational redshift would be at various points within an ordinary thin spherical shell.

Comment: @MattEdwards The redshift is the same everywhere at and inside the spherical shell.

Comment: safesphere, do you mean there would be no gravitational redshift seen at any point inside the sphere or a certain finite redshift?

Comment: @MattEdwards Please use the @ sign to address people (with no spaces). Otherwise no one receives your replies.

Comment: @MattEdwards Redshift is relative. When asking about a redshift somewhere, you must specify, relative to what or observed by whom. The redshift is the same inside and at the sphere. So for a person inside there is not redshift as observed by another person anywhere inside or standing on the shell. However a person outside the shell looking in can see a substantial redshift inside.